# How to make shapes on bottom and right of images with CSS?

Tags: css, image, shapes

I am creating a banner for website. First image shape is on `bottom rounded`, second image should be `right rounded`. I tried with `border-radius-left-bottom` and `right-bottom` but can't achieve good angle on this.

Could you give me some tips on what should I use for this shapes and how to put image below the first one.

Also how to make it works with green pattern below the first one and on the right of smaller images.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into trying clip-path?

Comment: Yeah, but is it working with all Browsers? I heard, clip-path is a problem with some browsers

Comment: True, according to caniuse IE does not sopport it so you’d need a fallback.